# SqlException 0x80131904 Connection Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed during the post-login phase. Unknown error 258

Tags: c#, sql-server, centos, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Есть рабочее приложение asp.net.core, работает на локальном компьютере и на appharbor.

Поднял свой CentOs7 сервер, на котором поставил nginx + kestrel и поднял этот сайт. Гонял виртуальную машину к контрольной точке "чистая операционка" пока не привёл скрипты ansbile к виду, который меня устроил: запускается, работает, SELinux включен, файерволл включен и т.п.

Так вот. Если открыть главную страницу - то всё работает. Но как только заходишь на страницу где нужно соединение с базой данных - то падает по таймауту с ошибкой "невозможно подключиться к SQL-серверу".

```
Jun 23 13:57:59 hostid appid: #033[40m#033[32minfo#033[39m#033[22m#033[49m: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
Jun 23 13:57:59 hostid appid: Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://site.tld/Account/Login application/x-www-form-urlencoded 236
Jun 23 13:57:59 hostid appid: #033[40m#033[32minfo#033[39m#033[22m#033[49m: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[1]
Jun 23 13:57:59 hostid appid: Executing action method CompanyName.Projectname.WebApp.Controllers.AccountController.Login (CompanyName.Projectname.WebApp) with arguments (CompanyName.Projectname.WebApp.Models.AccountViewModels.LoginViewModel, ) - ModelState is Valid
Jun 23 13:58:00 hostid appid: #033[40m#033[32minfo#033[39m#033[22m#033[49m: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10403]
Jun 23 13:58:00 hostid appid: Entity Framework Core 2.0.1-rtm-125 initialized 'ApplicationDbContext' using provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer' with options: None
Jun 23 13:58:15 hostid appid: #033[41m#033[30mfail#033[39m#033[22m#033[49m: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection[20004]
Jun 23 13:58:15 hostid appid: An error occurred using the connection to database 'dbname_prod' on server '1d000000000000000000000000000000056c.sqlserver.sequelizer.com'.
Jun 23 13:58:15 hostid appid: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Connection Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed during the post-login phase.  The connection could have timed out while waiting for server to complete the login process and respond; Or it could have timed out while attempting to create multiple active connections.  The duration spent while attempting to connect to this server was - [Pre-Login] initialization=294; handshake=377; [Login] initialization=7; authentication=12; [Post-Login] complete=14035;  ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): Unknown error 258
Jun 23 13:58:15 hostid appid: at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling)
Jun 23 13:58:15 hostid appid: at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
Jun 23 13:58:15 hostid appid: at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
Jun 23 13:58:15 hostid appid: at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
Jun 23 13:58:15 hostid appid: at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
Jun 23 13:58:15 hostid appid: at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
Jun 23 13:58:15 hostid appid: at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.WaitForPendingOpen()
Jun 23 13:58:15 hostid appid: --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
Jun 23 13:58:15 hostid appid: at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
Jun 23 13:58:15 hostid appid: at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Jun 23 13:58:15 hostid appid: at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.<OpenAsync>d__34.MoveNext()
Jun 23 13:58:15 hostid appid: ClientConnectionId:9b9ff986-f466-4ca6-bfd0-84086f9835d9
Jun 23 13:58:15 hostid appid: Error Number:-2,State:0,Class:11
Jun 23 13:58:15 hostid appid: #033[41m#033[30mfail#033[39m#033[22m#033[49m: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query[10100]
```

При этом sql-сервер очевидно работает без проблем:

- приложение с apphb подключается к хосту
- я с разных машин могу подключиться из SSMS
- конкретно с centos машины пробовал телнетиться на 1433

Проверил, что строка connection string используется правильная:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал даже при выключенном selinux и выключенном firewalld запустив приложение от root'а - всё равно таймаут.

Нагуглил много похожих тем, но ничего не помогло:

- [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Connection Timeout Expired](https://github.com/Microsoft/sqlopsstudio/issues/324)
- [What is causing this "The timeout period elapsed during the post-login phase."?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2b71a9b8-5089-4c47-99ca-f466e9c5e1fa/what-is-causing-this-quotthe-timeout-period-elapsed-during-the-postlogin-phasequot?forum=sqlintegrationservices)

В некоторых темах рекомендуют поставить на SQL сервер 2008 третий сервис-пак - и у меня как раз sql ver 10.50.1600.1 (что соответствует SQL Server 2008 R2 RTM), но во-первых, sql не мой, я могу только свою машину менять, а во-вторых, почему на appharbor всё работает и без этого.

В какую сторону копать?

Comment: с настройками авторизациии в бд никак не может быть связано?

Comment: помимо этого я бы ещё посмотрел секурные настройки субд

Comment: Подскажите, вы решили эту проблему или нет?

Comment: Мммм... сложно сказать, как починил - возможно просто ушёл на свой sql server.